# Can I use $(this) along with a css selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Can I use $(this) along with a css selector?

For example, if I want to do the following:

```
$(".toggle-nav").on("click", function(){
    $(".nav").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Is there any way that be shortened to the following or anything similar?

```
$(".toggle-nav").on("click", function(){
    $(this|".nav").toggleClass("active");
});
```

I know I could do this or something similar:

```
$(".toggle-nav").on("click", function(e){
    element = e.currentTarget;
    // get selector from e.currentTarget ...
    $("#"+element.id+",.nav").toggleClass("active");
});
```

But is there a jQuery way to do it?

Comment: Add is the proper use in this case, as you already have one of the elements.  There isn't a reason to include it in your css selector and look it up again.  You already have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way that be shortened to the following or anything
>   similar?

Use jquery [add](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$(this).add( ".nav" ).toggleClass("active");
```